# How to handle file uploads using JavaFX 2.x WebEngine

Tags: javafx-2

How do you upload a file to a web page rendered in JavaFX webview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to write a server side (servlet) to process a request from your JavaFX client.

Check this out [JavaFX: File upload to REST service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685970/javafx-file-upload-to-rest-service-servlet-fails-because-of-missing-boundary)